# Can't install VLC onto Debian headless server, dependency conflict with VLC:i386

Tags: debian, apt, vlc

I am trying to install VLC onto my Debian Server, however it conflicts with something.

Below are a few commands I have used to try debug where the issue might be, but I have absolutely no idea where to go next. Any pointers would be great as I ma totally stuck. If you need any more info just ask.

Thanks

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.1-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.1-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

.

```
$ aptitude why-not vlc
i   winetricks                        Recommends zenity | kdebase-bin
p   zenity:i386                       Provides   zenity
p   zenity:i386                       Depends    libnotify4:i386 (>= 0.7.0)
p   libnotify4:i386                   Recommends notification-daemon:i386
p   plasma-widgets-workspace:i386     Provides   notification-daemon:i386
p   plasma-widgets-workspace:i386     Depends    plasma-dataengines-workspace:i386 (= 4:4.11.13-2)
p   plasma-dataengines-workspace:i386 Depends    libakonadi-calendar4:i386 (>= 4:4.11.1)
p   libakonadi-calendar4:i386         Depends    libakonadi-contact4:i386 (= 4:4.14.2-2+b1)
p   libakonadi-contact4:i386          Depends    phonon:i386
p   phonon:i386                       Depends    phonon-backend-vlc:i386 | phonon-backend:i386
p   phonon-backend-vlc:i386           Recommends vlc:i386
p   vlc:i386                          Conflicts  vlc
```

Comment: What does `aptitude why-not vlc-nox` output?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a returning occurence of an [older question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/342888/how-can-i-solve-vlcs-dependency-vlc-nox)

As the original answer suggests, run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

first, then

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```